# Cannot access protected property in Slim

Tags: php, slim

I want to save 2 values in simple MySQL table with SLIM framework.

Here is my function :

```php
$app->post('/', function() use ($app) {
    $app= \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $db = connect_db();
    //submit_to_db($email, $subject, $message);
    $allPostVars = $app->request->post();
    $name = $allPostVars['name'];
    $id = $allPostVars['id'];

    $request = $db->prepare("insert into test values (name  , id )");
    $request->bindParam('name',$name, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $request->bindParam('id',$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $request->execute();

    $app->flash('message','Form submitted!');

    $app->redirect('./');
    // $app->render('form.php');
});

$app->run();
```

This is what I get after submitting :

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property Slim\Slim::$request in /opt/SLIM/form/index.php on line 29

Line 29 is

```php
$allPostVars = $app->request->post();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use...

`$allPostVars = $app->request()->post();`

Comment: I added the () to request , now I get another error, Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam()

Comment: it looks like your $db->prepare() is returning a mysqli object not PDO http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php

Comment: Thank you, you right, I changed my db connexion function to return a PDO.